# How to retrieve data from firebase 3.0 in an ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I have been meddling with the new docs for firebase which can be found 
here. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data

It was stated there that in order to retrieve data this would be used.

`firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var username = snapshot.val().username;
  // ...
});`

So, in my ionc app i converted it to

```
firebase.database().ref('/reports/' +'emergency').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
var user= snapshot.val().name;
console.log(user)
});
```

Here is a screenshot of my database.
[My Json Tree in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtzeL.png)

Problem is i just get an undefined output in the console. Anyone knows how to use and convert this code for ionic? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference what so ever in that code when using ionic. Your problem can be solved by console logging out snapshot.val() you will see that it actually is an object. It should look similar to:

```
{
key1:{
address:,
email:
...
},
key2:{
address:,
email:
...},
...

}
```

Basically the problem is that you are calling .name on snapshot.val() which actually is a property of its child.

Comment: var user= snapshot.val();
    console.log(user)  This code returns objects in the console. But what i want is to view ALL the names,address,email and timestamp in ionic just like a chatting app. any idea?   I'm clueless.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by listening to child events

```
var reportRef = firebase.database().ref('/reports/' +'emergency/').orderByKey();
reportRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
 console.log(data.val().email, data.val().name);  
});
```

Console log now shows results everytime data is saved.